# Coldfusion Lucee - How to output fields of JSON cfhttp return?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am making a cfhttp call to a service to get details related to service requests. I want to be able to output or store certain values that are coming back in the DB.

There is a main struct returned called member with most of the fields on that, but there are also sub structs called classtructure (for example) with a subset of fields and data I would need. See the attached images for more info.

When the data comes back here is how I am showing it currently.

```
<cfset content = #result.Filecontent#> 
<cfset data = #DeserializeJSON(content)#> 
<cfdump var="#data#">
```

When I try to say #data.description# it says that it doesn't exist. How do I reference the values and sub struct values to output them on the page?

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I wasn't referencing the object as arrays. This allows me to get to an individual field.

```
<cfdump var="#apikeyname.member[1].classstructure[1].description#">
```

Comment: You can use isDefined("apikeyname.member[1].classstructure[1].description") or a set of structKeyExists() and arrayLen() to check it before you reference it. I rarely use isDefined(), but when you have a very long nesting path, it is useful.